# What is the best wait command to use in Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I'm in the process of building an automated test pack in Selenium using Eclipse and Java. What I'm finding as I am going along is that sometimes certain actions can take longer than they did previously. So, whilst I am aware that I need to implement some kind of wait command I was wondering what would be the most effective one to use? Essentially, what I want is for the web page to wait for X seconds before it returns an error in the console.

Also, based on peoples past experience, what would be the best way of implementing this? I'm thinking that I create some kind of 'wait commands' class, which will have a series of methods that can be used depending on the scenario. Is this the right kind of approach?

Comment: They are **all** best! What have you tried? What worked? What did not work?

Comment: Hi Si, the reason I ask is that I've been advised against using a Thread.Sleep() as it means that the web page stops for the stipulated period of time. My utopia scenario would have each page  waiting for, maybe 10 seconds, so that the elements are all loaded up and can be located. I've used ImplicitWaits etc, but was just after some tips as to which are best to use in particular scenarios?

Comment: If the perfect solution existed, don't you think it would already be built into Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selenium has matured inbuilt wait mechanism.

It has implicit wait, which means when you navigate to a new page, it wait until the entire page loads, before doing any action on the page.

In places where Ajax is used, the above may not be of help, hence we have to use explicit wait to ensure ajax request is complete. ex:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

Check out the following link, for more details
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits

Comment: Thanks Deepak, I will have a look at this. Very informative

Comment: Don't forget Fluent waits. https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html I would imagine if you are trying to come up with the perfect solution, then Fluent waits would be the way to go.